# java process hangs while launching an executible that is using the file system

Tags: java, process

I'm trying to execute 'edena' bioinformatic program within my java code.
The process uses input files and write to output files.
when the input files are small (~1 MB) the process finishes and exits perfectly.
when the input files are larger (~ 80 MB) the process just hangs.
Invoking the process from cmd works just fine, so I suspect it got something to do with buffers etc..
I'm working on ubuntu 12.04.10 with 4GB RAM (don't know if it is relevant).
this is the code hanging:

```
String edena_exe1 = "edena -M 75 -p " + workshopDir + BinAssembly.cliqueFilesDir +         
"clique_" + c.getId() + " -DRpairs "+ workshopDir + BinAssembly.cliqueFilesDir +  
"/clique" + c.getId() + "pair1.fna " + workshopDir + 
BinAssembly.cliqueFilesDir + "/clique" + c.getId() + "pair2.fna ";
Process edena_proc1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(edena_exe1);
edena_proc1.waitFor();
```

thanks!

Comment: have you tried to run the command outside java

Comment: Just hangs? no exceptions?

Comment: It's looks like something that's easy to make a small mistake with. Did you try printing out `edena_exe1` before `exec` to see that it exactly matches the command-line command that works?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect with the larger input file the process generates more output.

When a process is started by the JVM it is given a limited buffered stream for output. If you do not bleed that stream while the process is running it may eventually fill up and block.

```
private static void dir() throws IOException {
  Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
  Process p = r.exec("DIR C:\\ /S");
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
  try {
    String line;
    // Bleed the output.
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
    }
  } finally {
    br.close();
  }
  // Just in case.
  p.destroy();
}
```